# Hibernate gets null for entity instance variables?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to implement a feature requires the form to load data for the logged in user.So I wrote a query to get these data for this user ID,Here is a code snippet from the school entity class:

```
public class ShSchool implements java.io.Serializable {
     private long schoolId;
     private GsDistrict gsDistrict;
}
```

I tried to get the data using the following query:

```
session.createQuery("from ShSchool where schoolId="+schoolId).list();
```

The problem is that I got values for primitive instance variables and got null for any other data types such as GsDistrict, So what is wrong and how could I got these objects values?

Thanks

Comment: Yes I think it is lazy loaded

Comment: I'm trying to access it's value and get null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible causes:

- The gsDistrict is indeed null for that particular user, check the DB to make sure it's not.
- The Hibernate mappings are incorrect.
- The gsDistrict is lazy loaded and you're accessing it outside the Hibernate session. In this case, however, I'd expect an exception to be thrown.

Please include the Hibernate mappings, the problem may be there.

Comment: Thanks octav I think I'm accessing it outside hibernate session.I think it could be solved if I change the lazy loading, Is there any possible solutions?

Comment: Hmm, lazy loading for a many-to-one relation ship is not something easily achievable in Hibernate from what I've read. Also, assuming it's lazy loading causing this, the gsDistrict should still not be null, it should be a proxy. So, since you're seeing the property as being null (as you said), I think the cause of this is something else. Please check the other 2 alternatives.. And posting the mappings would help! :)

Comment: A possibility to avoid lazy loading are NamedEntityGraphs. For example see here https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/ You can define which sets or lists should be in general lazy, but in specific situations eager loaded by using repository calls.